# How do you use Unix timestamps inside discord messages

Tags: text, discord, nextcord

[image: Formatted Dates in a Discord Message]

I'm trying to use Unix Timestamps within a Discord Message, can't find any information about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`format_dt`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/latest/api.html?highlight=format_dt#nextcord.utils.format_dt) in the docs.

Example:

```py
from nextcord.utils import format_dt
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()

# Short Time (9:18 AM)
short_time = format_dt(dt, "t")

# Long Time (9:18:58 AM)
long_time = format_dt(dt, "T")

# Short Date (04/03/2022)
short_date = format_dt(dt, "d")

# Long Date (April 3, 2022)
long_date = format_dt(dt, "D")

# Default (April 3, 2022 9:18 AM)
default_date_time = format_dt(dt, "f")

# Long Date Time (Sunday, April 3, 2022 9:18 AM)
long_date_time = format_dt(dt, "F")

# Relative Time (in 5 minutes / 1 day ago)
relative = format_dt(dt, "R")

...

# To send this in a command:
await ctx.send(f"{default_date_time} ({relative})")
```

Comment: How can I use this with a userinfo/serverinfo command? Is there a special **datetime** module to import?

Comment: @zzeua Things like user.created_at, etc. are already datetime objects, so you can use them directly in format_dt

Comment: ,How can I define dt & How can I use them in strftime ?

Comment: You can just do things like `format_dt(user.created_at, "f")` depending on what you want to format and which format you want. You don't need strftime to make discord timestamps, but those can take datetime objects as well.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really know about `format_dt` until now. Thank you for the answer and helping with my problems/errors :)

Comment: I have 1 other question, `await ctx.send(format_dt(member.created_at, "f")format_dt(member.created_at, "R"))` Im trying to put both in the same message. I tried to put it in a f str but, it doesn't work. im trying to put it as the image showed at the question. My question is how do I add both in the same message?

Comment: You can concatenate both into a single string or use an f-string like in the original example that I posted. Note, if you want to have it all on one line, you should use different types of quotes (eg. single quotes for the 'f' and 'R' inside the f-string.

Comment: ooh, thank you for answering my questions! Good luck in life! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Go to** https://www.epochconverter.com/ and get the *epoch timestamp* for the date and time you need using the Human date to Timestamp button. (eg. 1585890376)

**Inside your discord message**, format your message as such:

<t:########:#>

**Replace** `########` with your epoch timestamp,

**Replace** `#` with various letters for different options: `(f, F, D, t, T or R)`

**Example:**
For the current date, 2 years ago:

```
<t:1585890376:f>
April 3, 2020 1:06 AM
<t:1585890376:F>
Friday, April 3, 2020 1:06 AM
<t:1585890376:D>
April 3, 2020
<t:1585890376:t>
1:06 AM
<t:1585890376:T>
1:06:16 AM
<t:1585890376:R>
2 years ago
```